# How do I compile jzmq for ZeroMQ on OSX?

Tags: macos, pkg-config, zeromq, jzmq

Trying to follow the directions from: http://github.com/zeromq/jzmq

I installed pkg-config using Homebrew and then I run the following commands:
./autogen.sh
./configure

The configure fails with:

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
./configure: line 15263: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./configure: line 15263: `    PKG_CHECK_MODULES('
```

Comment: In case you want to compile jzmq for storm, get the code from this repository: https://github.com/asmaier/jzmq . It is a fork from https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq and contains two fixes to make the code compile on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with Java 1.7.0_25 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple list about jzmq building for MacOS.

1. Install brew

   https://brew.sh
2. Install tools for jzmq building

   ```
   brew install autoconf

   brew install automake

   brew install libtool

   brew install pkg-config

   brew install zeromq@3.2
   ```
3. Download jzmq source

   https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq source download to ~/somewhere/jzmq
4. Add symbolic link to /usr/local/include

   ```
   cd /usr/local/include

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/include/zmq.h

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/include/zmq_utils.h
   ```
5. Add symbolic linke to /usr/local/lib

   ```
   cd /usr/local/lib

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/lib/libzmq.3.dylib

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/lib/libzmq.a

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/lib/libmq.dylib

   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\@3.2/3.2.5/lib/pkgconfig/
   ```
6. Build jzmq-jni

   ```
   cd ~/somewhere/jzmq

   cd jzmq-jni


   ./autogen.sh

   ./configure

   make

   make install
   ```
7. Add option to VM options

VM options `-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 18):

A better solution is:

```
eval `brew --config | grep HOMEBREW_PREFIX | sed 's/: /=/'`
sudo bash -c 'echo '$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/share/aclocal' >> `aclocal --print-ac-dir`/dirlist'
```

This will allow the version of aclocal that ships with OSX to find *any* macros installed by homebrew packages.

Comment: This worked for me.  Maybe it should be promoted to be the answer?

Comment: Make to run ./autogen.sh after you do this, not just ./configure. After that it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

With homebrew, the key is the warning message:

```
~/code/foss/java/jzmq$ brew install pkg-config                                                                                    
==> Downloading http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.25.tar.gz
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25 --with-pc-path=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig
==> make install
Warning: m4 macros were installed to "share/aclocal".
Homebrew does not append "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
to "/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist". If an autoconf script you use
requires these m4 macros, you'll need to add this path manually.
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25: 8 files, 232K, built in 19 seconds
```

If you look at /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25/share/aclocal/, you will see:

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25/share/aclocal/                                                            
pkg.m4
```

You need to append /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25/share/aclocal/ to /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist,like this:

```
$ cat   /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist                                                                           
/usr/local/share/aclocal
/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25/share/aclocal/
```

And then re-run autogen and the other steps.

Answer (score 2):

From the zeromq [mailing list](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-April/003411.html):

> Building 0MQ from the development
>   trunk on a UNIX style OS (Linux, OS X)
>   requires that pkg-config
>   (http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/)
>   be installed.  A regular source build
>   of 0MQ does not require pkg-config. 
>   On Mac OS X, pkg-config does not come
>   with the system, so when you try to do
>       ./configure you may see errors like:
>
> ```
> ./configure: line 23913: syntax error near unexpected token `GLIB,'
> ./configure: line 23913: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB, glib-2.0 gthread-2.0)'
> ```
>
> To resolve this, you need to install
>   the latest pkg-config:
>
> ```
> tar xzf pkg-config-0.25.tar.gz 
> cd pkg-config-0.25 
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pkg-config-0.25 --datarootdir=/usr/share 
> make 
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> Then you will need to put
>   `/usr/local/pkg-config-0.25/bin` on your
>   $PATH.  It is important to include the
>   `"--datarootdir=/usr/share"` option,
>   which will install the pkg.m4 file in
>   `/usr/share/aclocal`, where aclocal will
>   be able to find it.
>
> Then you can build 0MQ:
>
> ```
> cd zeromq2 
> ./autogen.sh  # must do this again after installing pkg-config
> ./configure   # add other options here 
> make 
> sudo make install
> ```

Edited to reflect latest pkg-config version (0.25).

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same question, and I don't feel this is answered. I also installed ZeroMQ and pkg-config via Homebrew. /usr/local/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 exists and comes from pkg-config 0.25. It seems that Homebrew has satisfied the requirements listed but it still fails.

Comment: If you want it to just work out of the box, don't install using homebrew. Install it by downloading and compiling it yourself.

Comment: I use tools like MacPorts or Homebrew so I don't have to monkey around with hand-compiling stuff. But, in this case, I wonder if the pkg-config file for ZeroMQ is correct. By hand-editing (ugh!) the Makefile for jzmq I was able to get it to install correctly.

Comment: Actually symlinking the `pkg.m4` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compile [jzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq) on Mac OS X, proved to be a bit of a headache.  I followed the instructions above.  I was still getting following error

> syntax error near unexpected token
>   `PKG_CHECK_MODULES

The instructions above tell you to copy the *pkgk.m4* file into */usr/share/aclocal*, but your directory might be different.  Basically you need the dir that *automake* searches for macro definitions.

The _PKG_CHECK_MODULES_ macro is defined in the *pkg.m4* file.  This file must be installed in the [appropriate directory](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Macro-Search-Path.html), which is searched by *automake*.  Somehow automake is installed twice on my OS X, one in */usr* and another in */Developer/usr*.  Make sure you know which one it's using.  Just do *which automake*.  If yours in is */Developer/usr*, then copy the *pkg.m4* file to */Developer/usr/share/aclocal*.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I didn't have pkg-config installed.

Comment: Me too, doing `brew install pkg-config` fixed it

Answer (score 0):

On Osx Mountain Lion I don't have the dirlist file as Phil Calçado said, but a simple symlink from `/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/[version]/share/aclocal/pkg.m4` to `/usr/share/aclocal` made the trick and now jzmq build fine.