# Getting error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path in IntelliJ ide with windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, zeromq, jzmq

I have a java project which have zeromq implementation. i have installed zeromq windows version in my windows 10 OS.
When running the application i am getting above error.
I have downloaded zeromq (windows) installer from http://zeromq.org/area:download and installed it in C:\ZeroMQ4.0.4 folder.
Any idea what further action i have to take?

As i am not able to successfully work it in windows i have installed it in a ubuntu 16 vm under my windows 10 machine

Steps i have done are
Installed java in ubuntu

apt-get install -y libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake uuid-dev libzmq3-dev checkinstall

Download Required Package
wget https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-x/releases/download/v4.0.8/zeromq-4.0.8.tar.gz

wget https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/archive/v2.2.2.zip

tar -xzf zeromq-4.0.8.tar.gz

unzip v2.2.2.zip

Install ZMQ
cd zeromq-4.0.8

./configure

make

checkinstall     it will creat deb package to be removed easily if required

ldconfig

install jzmaq

cd jzmq-2.2.2/

./autogen.sh

./configure

make

make install

*** In case error show up  --- autogen.sh: error: could not find libtool.  libtool is required to run autogen.sh. run the mentioned command.
ln -s /usr/bin/libtoolize /usr/bin/libtool

## Set java_home path in ubuntu

Still i am getting same error when debugging it from my windows 10 machine with Intellij IDE

Comment: DLL files must be in the process working directory or in system PATH environment. You can also add it to a PATH as `-Djava.library.path=...` VM option, specifying the location of the directory that contains DLL files. You set it in VM Options field of the run/debug configuration.

Comment: which dll files?

Comment: zeroMQ ones. It seems that it needs native DDL libraries to work, see [this thread](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/231) and [this comment](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/231#issuecomment-18854044).

Comment: I am trying it on windows 10 machine (not on any linux flavor)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092576/2000323 how to add it to path on Windows and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48057894/2000323 about similar issue.

Comment: What now i have tried is installed zmq,java and jzmq in a vmware image of ubuntu. all installation did successfully. But when i am trying to debug app from My windows base system I am still getting same error

Comment: Have tried -Djava.library.path=/home/jzmq-2.2.2/src/zmq.jar but still it didn't work